# hibernate: Many to Many relationship with View and table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to query between a view and a table, using hibernate.

I prepare 3 projections, something like `SELECT id, name, storages`

hibernate entities are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cl_libraryWithItems_view")
public class LibraryWithItemsViewModel implements Serializable {
    .... other columns

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_library_id", inverseName = "fk_storage_id")
    @JoinTable(name = "cl_library_storage",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="library_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="storage_id")})
    Set<StorageModel> storages = new HashSet<StorageModel>();
```

second entity (i'm only including the relevant columns)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cl_storage")
public class StorageModel implements Serializable {
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "storages")
    private final Set<LibraryModel> libraries = new HashSet<LibraryModel>();
}
```

I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I looked under the hood, and it appears that error is thrown in the following spot.

In `SimpleProjection.java`, line 90, number of columns for storage column is 0. For first two columns, I get 1.

```
int numColumns =  getColumnCount( criteria, criteriaQuery );
```

in same file, elsewhere,

```
public int getColumnCount(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        Type types[] = getTypes( criteria, criteriaQuery );
        int count = 0;
        for ( int i=0; i<types.length; i++ ) {
            count += types[ i ].getColumnSpan( criteriaQuery.getFactory() );
        }
        return count;
    }
```

This messes up line 164 in `CriteriaLoader` (out of bounds is thrown here)

```
result[i] = types[i].nullSafeGet(rs, columnAliases[pos], session, null);
```

An additional detail, in `CollectionType.java` the getColumnSpan returns 0. Since we are expecting collection, this method gets triggered, and returns 0.

```
public int getColumnSpan(Mapping session) throws MappingException {
    return 0;
}
```

So the problem appears to be that, our column a collection, and getColumnSpan returns 0.

Now the question is how to fix it. What do I need to do, so I can successfully project the `storages` column?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920678/getting-all-objects-with-a-certain-element-inside-a-collection-of-strings-with-c, it appears there is an open bug for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something really silly.

I wanted to do a bi-directional mapping, but what I was doing was not bi-directional.

`LibraryWithItemsViewModel` had a set of `StorageModel`. `StorageModel` needs to have a set of `LibraryWithItemsViewModel` as well.

This problem goes away with this change. More dragons lurk ... but a tale for another day.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set ManyToMany bidirectional Relationship and avoid many problems, is to create a third Table mapped to entity, this entity must have ManyToOne to each of those tables

the table must have a composite primary Key compounded of two fields whose names are like this : table1_primarikeyoftable1 and table2_primarykeyoftable2
 and two foreign key in those tables
it works fine and you can add some other fields in this third table if you need.

Comment: well, that is how sql would work. I expect hibernate takes care of this implicitly. Or is this assumption wrong?